# Removing all standalone occurences of a word from a string with regular expressions in Java

Tags: java, regex

Need advice on how to replace a sub-string like: *@sometext*, but not replace *"@someothertext@somemail.com"* sub-string.

For example, when I've got a string something like:

*An example with @sometext and also with "@someothertext@somemail.com" sometextafter*

And the result, after replacing sub-strings in string above should look like:

*An example with and also with "@someothertext@somemail.com" sometextafter*

After getting string from a field, I'm using:

```
String textMod = someText.replaceAll("( |^)[^\"]@[^@]+?( |$)","");
someText = textMod + "@\"" + someone.getEmail() + "\" ";
```

And then I'm setting this string into field.

Comment: Is the rule to remove every word beginning with @ unless it is in quotation marks or to remove every word beginning with @ that has only one @ or to remove every word beginning with @ except those that appear to be valid email addresses...

Comment: have you already tried something by yourself?

Comment: @1 the rule is to leave the model: "@sometext@somemail.com" and to remove only @sometext model in text.

Comment: Removing the initial question and providing no information on what you did to solve your problem helps no one. Instead answer yourself and accept your own answer if none of the provided were sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a regex on a standalone occurence this way

```
\b@sometext\b
```

Putting the \b in front and in the back of the @sometext will make sure that it's a standalone word, not part of another word like @someothertext@sometext.com. Then if it's found the result will be put inside $match, now you can do whatever you want with $match

Hope this helps

> From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html
>
> The \b in the pattern indicates a word boundary, so only the distinct 
>   * word "web" is matched, and not a word partial like "webbing" or "cobweb"

```
if (preg_match("/\bweb\b/i", "PHP is the web scripting language of choice."))      {
    echo "A match was found.";
    }
```

> ^ PHP example but you get the point

Answer (score 1):

If there is always a space before and behind the tags to replace, this might suffice.

```
/\s(@\w+)\s/g
```

Answer (score 1):

This should correspond to your needs:

```
str = str.replaceAll("@\w+[^@]", "");
```

Comment: This would match @hello@somemail.

Comment: @ohaal No, as `[^@]` means *not an arobase* !

Comment: Yes, but it would result in two hits: "@hell" and "@somemail.", which means "@somemail." would be deleted.

Comment: @sinsedrix it will match "hell" as `\w+` and "o" as `[^@]` and will remove "@hello" from `@hello@somemail`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
(?<!\w)@[^@\s]+(?!\S)
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?303pp)

Match on a `@` but only if there is no word character `\w` before `(?<!\w)`. Then match a sequence of characters that are not `@` and not whitespace `\s` but only if its not followed by a non whitespace `\S`

`(?<!\w)` is called a [negative lookbehind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

`[^@\s]` is called a [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), means match anything that is not part of the class

`(?!\S)` is a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Answer (score 1):

Simply adding spaces before and after "@sometext" would not work if "@sometext" is at the start or end of a sentence. However, just adding a pattern checking for start or end of sentence would not work either, as when you match "@sometext " at the start of a sentence and leave a space " ", this will make the resulting string look strange. Same goes for the end of a sentence.

We need to split the regex replace in to two actions, and perform two seperate regex replaces:

```
str = str.replaceAll(" @sometext ", " ");
str = str.replaceAll("^@sometext | @sometext$|(?:@sometext ){2,}", "");
```

`^` means start of line, `$` means end of line.

EDIT: Added corner case handling of when several @sometext's are after each other.

Answer (score 1):

(c#, regex based)

```
//match @xxx sequences, but only if i can look back and NOT see a @xxx immediately preceding me, and if I don't end with a @
string input = @"[An example with @hello and also with ""@@hello@somemail.com"" sometext @lastone";
 var pattern = @"(?<!@\w+)(?>@\w+)(?!@)";
 var matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
```

Answer (score 0):

`myString = myString.replaceAll(" @hello ", " ");`

If `@hello` is a single word, then it has spaces before and after, right? So you should find all `@hello`s with space before and after and replace it with a space.

If you need to remove not only `@hello`s and all words which are starting with `@` and not containing other `@`, use this:

`myString = myString.replaceAll(" @[^@]+? ", " ");`

`[^@]` is any symbol except `@`. `+?` means match **at least** one character until reaching the first space.

If you want to remove words with only alphanumeric characters, use `\\w` instead of `[^@]`

**EDIT:**

Yeah, ohaal's right. To make it match at the start and the end of string use this pattern:

`( |^)@[^@]+?( |$)`

`myString = myString.replaceAll("( |^)@hello( |$)", " ");`

Comment: This will not match `@hello` at start or end of lines.

Comment: yes, you're right.It also will work not correctly if there are two or more `@hello`s together. for example `a @hello @hello @hello b`.But I think he will not meet this case.

Comment: Your current solution will match all the cases except the one you last mentioned. You could solve this adding an `|(?:@hello ){2,}`, which would then match repeating "@hello " (minimum 2 reoccurences). A problem I see with your current solution is that you will leave a space at the start or end of a line if "@hello" is replaced there. See my solution for reference.